# How does Ubuntu 12.04 link to windows user profile?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I'm playing around with various Linux distros and have so far tested Ubuntu briefly on my desktop dual booting alongside Windows 7. To my pleasant surprise, it detected users on my Windows partition and offered to link my user profile there to my home folder (well, pictures, documents, etc). Now I'm installing Debian, and I'm assuming I'll need to do that manually.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu removed this package from the latest release because of the bugs, in most cases the user was detected but nothing was copied from the Windows partition into the Linux partition.

For now the best way to do this is to just do it manually, but you can also create a script, that starts with the session and just create a symlink into the users folder, and then mounts the Windows partition at every start in order to have access to it.

I thing that should do it. I had the same problem, but at that time I dind't knew enough to create a script like that. Now that I have the "knowledge" I don't have a Windows partition to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is done by the package called [migration assistant](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MigrationAssistance)  ,it is removed due to stability issues

> Now I'm installing Debian, and I'm assuming I'll need to do that
>   manually.

yeah

> What's the best way to do this?

copy paste the docs manually  after installing the os